# Stack Overflow in XmlReader C#

Tags: c#, xmlreader, stack-overflow

this code throws me an error.
I explain the error in the code:

```
public partial class Util
{
    public string LoadFunctions()
    {

        string codeFunctionsString = "";

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("fname2.xml");
        //The line above throws an error:
        //"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
        //The file DOES exist, so I don't know what the problem is.

        reader.Read();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            reader.ReadToFollowing("item");
            //reader.
            codeFunctionsString += reader.Value + "|";

            Form1 win = new Form1();

            win.CodeInput.Text += reader.Value + " ";

        }
        return codeFunctionsString;
    }
}
```

Comment: @patrick , why do you have two ?? reader.read()???

Comment: @can you post your content of frame.xml aslo

Comment: @patrick instantite a form from a util class , something very wrong there?? you should acess util class froma a form but not the opposite...its bad design

Comment: can you put a stack trace.. may be it was thrown by some other function.. because XmlReader doesn't throw StackOverflow exception

Comment: I think this is the code which is throwing error Form1 win = new Form1();

            win.CodeInput.Text += reader.Value + " ";

Comment: Is Form1 calling `LoadFunctions`, by any chance?

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised to find that opening the file causes a stack overflow exception. Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to verify that the exception really is happening at that line?

Comment: @Mike that is correct. 
Also, how can I trace something to the VCS debugger?
@gov I'm only accessing the Form1 class to test that the XML reader is working properly, by the time I've finished it it'll do something completely different.

Comment: @Patrick: I've added an answer to the main question. As for tracing, use this: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("whatever");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment-based question, here's what's going on.

```
class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponents();

        Util u = new Util();
        string functions = u.LoadFunctions();
    }
}
```

In this case, I'm guessing that the call is in either the constructor (as above), or in `Form1_Load` (not shown, but same idea).

Well, what happens is that when you call `LoadFunctions`, it creates a `Form1`, which calls `LoadFunctions`, which creates a `Form1`, which calls `LoadFunctions`, which creates a `Form1`, which calls `LoadFunctions`, which creates a `Form1`, which calls `LoadFunctions`, which creates a `Form1`, which calls `LoadFunctions`, which creates a `Form1`, which-**ERROR: StackOverflowException**

The resolution is to either not create a form in `LoadFunctions` (perhaps, make it an argument you pass in?), or don't call `LoadFunctions` in `Form1`.

Comment: Oh wow, I never realized I was doing that!
Thanks a ton for your reply. :)

Comment: My pleasure. If someone learns something, then the world becomes a better place :)